# Players cannot open chests or doors

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am making a Dayz server, and right before we were about to open, my friend noticed that players could not open chests. It works for op. I have tried adding essentials.build to pex, but still nothing. I uninstalled Myz, still nothing. Can someone help me?

Plugin List:
Builder
Citizens
Clear Lag
EasyItemRename
ecoCreature
Essentials
Factions
Modifyworld
Monster_Apocalypse
Multiverse-Core
Multiverse-Portals
NoCheatPlus
PermissionsEx
PluginMetrics
SignEdit
SignRanksPlus
SwornGuns
Updater
Vault
WorldEdit
WorldGuard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the doors are close to spawn then minecraft's built in spawn protection may be blocking it. In your minecraft server.properties there should be a line that says "spawn-protection=16" Change that to 0 to turn minecraft's spawn protection off hope that works for you!